# what is the fastest way to feed video frames to tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow

there is a pre-trained `Tensorflow` model for image recognition.  I want to use it as a feature extractor.

In order to increase performance  Video Frames are read with `cv2.read()`  and buffered in `frameBuffer`. 
In the next step I choose a batch of images and feed them to graph after a set of pre-processes(in order to prepare images for feeding):

```
for x in range ( lowerIndex,upperIndex):
   frame = frameBuffer[x]
   img_data = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100]
   result, img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
   img_str = img_str.tostring(order='C')
   batchFrameBuffer.append(img_str)
```

pre-process step takes a significant time and during this time the utilization of GPU is 0. 
Is there a way to keep GPU working all the time? (for example using different threads (one for read and preprocess and another for running session)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tensorflow has the `data.Dataset` specifically for this. Check it out [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets).

You could create a `dataset` from `frame_buffer`, and then you can `map` a function to that `dataset`.

The function however needs to be tensorflow ops, but you need `cv2` functions. For this, use `tf.py_func` as it allows you to wrap normal python code as tensorflow ops, read about it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func).

The benefit of using `dataset` is that the multithreading is done in `C++` by Tensorflow, rather than you having to manually do it in `Python`. You can even set the number of parallel threads as a parameter in `dataset.map`.

Once you have your `dataset` object, you can create an `iterator` from it, and build your graph starting from the iterator, so the over head of using `feed_dict` is avoided as well.

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#optimizing_for_gpu) is a general Tensorflow performance guide for GPUs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Squadrick's answer is probably the best idea but I also want to suggest preprocessing the video to extract frames as an independent step. If you have space for it, it'd be useful to have those frames independently. A lot of public video datasets (Amsterdam Ordinary Video Library, ImageNet VOD on Kaggle now) supply each video as a folder of jpegs, frame1.jpg, frame2.jpg etc). It saves decoding the video each time you want to train a new model. It’ll eat a lot of cpu and use a good amount of space, but it’ll speed up your model training. I’ve found mpeg frame extraction in opencv (C version) to be fairly slow, even just to display a frame.

Also, maybe FFMPEG could do your frame extraction to RGB as an independent step. Re-Encoding to jpeg only to decode back to RGB for model training is using CPU to save on disk space.

Comment: Did you notice it to be slow as well with mpeg4 codec ? 
I found mpeg4 is twice as fast as h264 for decoding. 
Still considering the pros and cons of storing the videos as JPGs vs storing as .mp4.

Comment: @jhagege, please make sure your JPG compression is "lossless". Multiple compression is something that machine learning models will use as a short cut if they can, but lossless compression prevents this. The speed of decoding will vary most with the "size" of the videos (spatial, temporal size), but it *should* at least be almost real-time (30fps). Interesting that mpeg4 seemed faster, though.